# Validating Email using html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am having a textbox in my form :

```
<input type="text" pattern="/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+)\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/" title="Enter Valid EmailId" name="NEmail" placeholder="New Email Id" id="txtNewId"/>
```

Now ,even if i enter a valid email id on click of submit button it still shows it invalid.Please help where i am wrong.

Comment: why don't you just use `<input type="email">`?

Comment: The input must be in a form -> http://jsfiddle.net/WvV43/

Comment: @adeneo It is in the form in my case too.But still wrong answer and its wrong in fiddle too.Please check

Comment: The obvious problem is that is assumes the TLD can only have 2 to 4 characters in it.

Comment: It forbids `+` characters from appearing in the name part too. That's wrong.

Comment: The biggest problem is that the email pattern is much more complex than the one you are using, here an actual email pattern: http://ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html you can however just use /.+@.+\..+/i which may validate some incorrect email, but will never invalidate some corrects one

Comment: Don't validate that much on the client side, since client side validation can easily skipped. Just use <input type="email">. I always had problems validating email addresses since my language consist of many non-standard letters like öäü. Most of the RegEx-codes to validate an E-Mail Address don't include support for these special chars. You should validate the E-Mail on the server side and just check for '@' and MinLength(5) on the client side. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this.

```
<input type="email" name="NEmail" placeholder="New Email Id" id="txtNewId" />
```

then no need to write the pattern. :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
pattern = "/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([  -.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Answer:

This is HTML not JS, you don't need to add /^ and and$/.

```
<input type="text" pattern="([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+)\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})" />
```

1. Answer:

Combine pattern with type=email:

```
<input type="email" pattern=".+\@.+\.([A-Za-z]{2,})" />
```